# how to extract bash array elements that match regex

Tags: arrays, bash, dataset

Inside a bash script, one can employ an array as a dataset, in which each element is a record and individual records contain fields. For instance, a record could correspond to an individual dog and the fields could include "dogbreed" (the supposed ancestry of the dog) and "dogfood" (what the dog likes to eat).

Suppose we want to know what the pitbulls in our array like to eat. There are at least two ways to do this. We could loop through the elements and apply a regex to each element. Or we could use printf to turn the array into a single multiline string, and then regex-search the string. The following script demonstrates that the printf method is several times faster than the loop method.

Is there a better way to perform this task inside bash? My computer uses BSD unix with `GNU bash, version 3.2.57`, so  associative arrays are not available.

```
#!/bin/bash  
# bash array: (1) extract elements where field1 matches a regex; (2) from only these elements, extract the value of field2.
# The fields in an array are announced by ":fieldname:" without the quotes and can appear anywhere in the element. 
# Compare speed of competing methods; confirm that printf is much faster than explicit bash loop
# In this example, 
# (1) we select all elements for which dogbreed equals pitbull; 
# (2) then only from these elements do we extract (print) the dogfood field. If there is no dogfood field in an element, we print nothing.
# Note that if an element merely contains the string "pitbull", this does not imply that it is selected.  
# Limitation/assumption: each field appears no more than once in a record.
# Limitation/assumption: no array element contains newline character / linefeed / LF.  

if [[ $1 = 0 ]]
then
    method=printf
elif [[ $1 = 1 ]]
then
    method=loop
else
    printf '%s\n' "\"\$1\"=\"$1\" must be either 0 for printf or 1 for loop."
    exit 1
fi

unset longarray
declare -a longarray
longarray+=( "dog" )
for index in {1..6} # BEWARE! replacing 6 with a much larger number could define an array with more elements than exist in the universe, thereby overloading the most powerful supercomputer.
    do 
        longarray+=( "${longarray[@]}" )
    done
longarray+=( 
"pitbull licked my face :dogfood: human sweat " 
":dogbreed:chihuahua : licked my face :dogfood: human sweat " 
" and so they said :dogfood: Wolf's Tooth :dogdefault: well-trained :dogbreed: pitbull and what's ever"
"horse flea doggy :dogbreed: pitbull :dogtype:friendly :dogdefault:abused piggy wig" )
longarray=( "shark, great white; :dogbreed:    pitbull :dogfood:bad people :nothing at all" "${longarray[@]}" )
longarray=( 
"${longarray[@]}" 
":dogfood: Wolf's Tooth :nothing shark, great white; :dogbreed:pitbull"

":dogfood: Absolutely no chocolate!!  :dogbreed:   pitbull shark, great white; :dogbreed:pitbull"

"great white shark :dogbreed:pitbull"
)
{
    printf 'length of array:%s\n' "${#longarray[@]}"
    declare -p method
}>/dev/stderr

time {
if [[ $method = printf ]] 
then
    :
    perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; use 5.18.4; if (s/.*:dogfood:\s*([^:]+).*/$1/) { print; };' <( perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; use 5.18.4; if (m/.*:dogbreed:\s*pitbull\b/)  { print;};' <( printf '%s\n' "${longarray[@]}" ) )
elif [[ $method = loop ]] 
then
    for ephemeral in "${longarray[@]}"
    do
        perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; use 5.18.4; if (s/.*:dogfood:\s*([^:]+).*/$1/) { print; };' <( perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; use 5.18.4; if (m/.*:dogbreed:\s*pitbull\b/)  { print;};'  <( printf '%s\n' "$ephemeral" ) )
    done
else
    declare -p method
    printf '%s\n' "must be either printf or loop."
    exit 1
fi
}
```

Comment: is this a learning exercise? Else why not use `awk` which has had assoc arrays since its invention? Arg, calling `perl` from a shell script is almost always uneeded. Do it there, or do it in `awk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

subshell `grep` to grab relevant elements in one pass?

```
$: ray=( $( seq 1 5000 ) )
$: echo ${#ray[@]} 
5000
# pipe array elements through grep for string you want
$: subset=( $( printf '%s\n' "${ray[@]}" | grep '123' ) )
$: echo ${#subset[@]}
15
$: echo "${subset[@]}"
123 1123 1230 1231 1232 1233 1234 1235 1236 1237 1238 1239 2123 3123 4123
```

For more specific matching, you might need layered conditions. In that case, I usually use `sed`, because you can embed subconditions inside `/.../{ ... }' braced block constructs, though here it may not be needed.

Try -

```
printf "%s\n" "${longarray[@]}" | 
  sed -En '/\s*:{0,1}\bdogbreed:{0,1}\s*\bpitbull\b/p'
```

That will match:

```
shark, great white; :dogbreed:    pitbull :dogfood:bad people :nothing at all
and so they said :dogfood: Wolf's Tooth :dogdefault: well-trained :dogbreed: pitbull and what's ever
horse flea doggy :dogbreed: pitbull :dogtype:friendly :dogdefault:abused piggy wig
```

Also matches:

```
dogbreed pitbull
dogbreed: pitbull
dogbreed      pitbull
dogbreed:      pitbull
dogbreed:pitbull
:dogbreed pitbull
:dogbreed: pitbull
dogbreed pitbull:
!dogbreed pitbull!
```

But not:

```
dogbreeds pitbull
dogbreed pitbulls
mydogbreed pitbull
dogbreed::pitbull
dogbreed :pitbull
```

Spec matters.

Comment: so... `hits=( printf '%s\n' "${longarray[@]}" | grep 'pitbull')` ?

Comment: I'd still use `perl` or `awk`.

Comment: Nope. That grabs any record that includes "pitbull". My code grabs only records that have dogbreed field equal to "pitbull" and then extracts the value of dogfood field from them. This is a way to use an array as a dataset, with records and fields (or units and attributes), not just to find a pattern in an array.

Comment: Insufficient details on the data spec. I was just offering an example from which to extrapolate. is `dogbreed pitbull` just noise, or is it as valid as `:dogbreed: pitbull`? Is the space after `:dogbreed:` optional? Do you have ***ANY*** control over this content?

Answer (score 0):

The following script dispenses with the proof that the printf method is faster than the loop method, and dispenses with hard-coding of field names inside the perl code.

```
#!/bin/bash  
# use a bash array as a dataset, with records and fields within records.
# Limitation/assumption: each field appears no more than once in a record.
# Limitation/assumption: no array element contains newline character / linefeed / LF.  

unset longarray
declare -a longarray
longarray+=( "dog" )
for index in {1..3} # BEWARE! replacing 6 with a much larger number could define an array with more elements than exist in the universe, thereby overloading the most powerful supercomputer.
    do 
        longarray+=( "${longarray[@]}" )
    done
# create example array=dataset
longarray+=( 
"pitbull licked my face :dogfood: human sweat " 
":dogbreed:chihuahua : licked my face :dogfood: human sweat " 
" and so they said :dogfood: Wolf's Tooth :dogdefault: well-trained :dogbreed: pitbull and what's ever"
"horse flea doggy :dogbreed: pitbull :dogtype:friendly :dogdefault:abused piggy wig" )
longarray=( "shark, great white; :dogbreed:    pitbull :dogfood:bad people :nothing at all" "${longarray[@]}" )
longarray=( 
" dogbreed pitbull"
"${longarray[@]}" 
":dogfood: Wolf's Tooth :nothing shark, great white; :dogbreed:pitbull"
":dogfood: Absolutely no chocolate!!  :dogbreed:   pitbull shark, great white; :dogbreed:pitbull"
"great white shark :dogbreed:pitbull"
)

{
    printf 'length of array:%s\n' "${#longarray[@]}"
    chooserecordfield="dogbreed"
    chooserecordregex="pitbull"
    choosefieldfield="dogfood"
    choosefieldregex="Wolf's Tooth"
    declare -p chooserecordfield
    declare -p chooserecordregex
    declare -p choosefieldfield
}>/dev/stderr

printf '%s\n' "records such that ${chooserecordfield}=${chooserecordregex} and ${choosefieldfield} is not missing or blank:"

printf '%s\n' "${longarray[@]}" | perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; 
    my $perl_chooserecordfield=$ARGV[0];
    my $perl_chooserecordregex=$ARGV[1];
    my  $perl_choosefieldfield=$ARGV[2];
    while (<STDIN>) { 
        unless (m/:$perl_chooserecordfield:\s*$perl_chooserecordregex/) { next; } ; 
        if (s/.*:$perl_choosefieldfield:\s*([^:]+)\s*.*/$1/)  {  print;  }; 
    }
          ' "${chooserecordfield}" "${chooserecordregex}" "${choosefieldfield}"
```